# Running two functions parallely in Vitis HLS that have different Initiation Intervals?

Tags: xilinx, vivado-hls

How to synthesize a top function that instantiates two independent functions with different Initiation Intervals and make them run in parallel, keeping the II of top function to the minimum of II's of the two functions?

```html
#include <iostream>
 
struct data1{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};
 
struct data2{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};
 
int proc1(data1 data){
    #pragma HLS PIPELINE II=3
    
    int t = data.a^2 + data.b^2;
    int q = t*data.a*data.b;
    int ret = data.c?t:q;
    return ret;
}
 
int proc2(data2 data){
    #pragma HLS PIPELINE II=1
    int q = data.a*data.b;
    int t = t^2 + data.a^2 + data.b^2;
    int ret = data.c?t:q;
    return ret;
}
 
int top_func(data1 d1, data2 d2){
    #pragma HLS PIPELINE II=1
    int out1, out2;
    out1 = proc1(d1);
    out2 = proc2(d2);
 
    int x = out1*out2;
    return x;
}
```

This code shows the gist of what i wanted, I have proc1 function with II=3 ad proc2 function with II=1. I want my top function with an II=1, but that nots what i am getting. The tool makes the II of the top function to 3. Is there any pragma or directive that will make the II of top function as 1?

Here is the Schedule Viewer graph after the C synthesis:
[Schedule Viewer Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIGGH.png)

Comment: How can this be possible? Even if the proc1 and proc2 run in parallel, the multiplication has to wait for both of them to finish, hence the II will take the worst of the two. You should see if you open the scheduling graph

Comment: @Fra93 Yeah the multiplication should finish and only then the output will be ready, but that would only affect the latency right. I am fine with having higher latency, but the Initiation Interval (II) can be 1, as the entire design is pipelined. Correct me if I am missing anything?

Comment: May you update the question with the scheduling view after C synthesis?

Comment: @Fra93 I have updated the question with the schedule viewer

Answer (score 0):

Please check the user guide [UG902](https://docs.xilinx.com/v/u/en-US/ug902-vivado-high-level-synthesis):

> Initiation Interval (II):  Number of clock cycles before the function
> can accept new input data.

By definition the II of the TLF cannot be smaller than any functions it calls. It has to wait at least that amount of clock cycles before the function can be called again. If you really need an II of 1 then you may try to reduce II of proc1 by adding pragmas to assist HLS. Refer to [UG902](https://docs.xilinx.com/v/u/en-US/ug902-vivado-high-level-synthesis) for more information on how to do so.